# Analytic function satisfying given conditions is constant

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Let $f$ be analytic in in $|z| \leq 1$ and let $|f(z)|$ be maximized for $|z| \leq 1$ at $z_0$ with $|z_0|=1$. Prove that $|f'(z_0)| \neq 0$ unless $f$ is a constant.

My approach: By the maximum modulus theorem, $|f(z_0)| \geq |f(z)|$ for all $|z| \leq 1.$  This yields $|f'(z_0)| \geq 0$ in $|z| \leq 1.$ I don't know how to complete the problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What does it mean for a function to be analytic in a closed set?  Also, the Maximum Modulus Principle is formulated for open sets.

Comment: A closed and bounded set (as in this problem) is compact. So $f$ achieves it's maximum on the boundary.

Comment: Not what I asked.  The definition of analyticity at a point involves certain properties of the function in an open neighborhood of that point.  Just like ``differentiable on $[a, b]$'' for a function of a real variable is not clear, has to be augmented by conventions (one-sided derivatives at the endpoints, or differentiable in an open set that contains $[a, b]$).

Comment: @MartinR This isn't a counter-example, since your $f$ satisfies $|f'(z_0)|\neq 0$.

Comment: @JoshKeneda: You are right. I had misread as $f'(z) \ne 0$ in the disk. – Will delete comment.

Comment: So is my approach wrong ? Thank you for your time. I still couldn't do this.

Comment: @avs implicitely $f(z)$ analytic on $|z| \le 1$ means $f(z)$ analytic on an open containing $|z|\le 1$ (and it is compatible with the definition that $f(z)$ equals its (complex) Taylor series on the neighborhood of each point)

Answer (score 1):

Let $D=\{z: |z|\leq 1\}.$ WLOG , for easier calculation assume $f(z_0)\in \mathbb R^+.$ Suppose $f$ is not constant on $D$.

(1). By contradiction, suppose $f'(z_0)= 0.$ Then for some $n\in \mathbb N $ with $n\geq 2$ we have $f(z)=f(z_0)+(z-z_0)^ng(z)$ for all $z\in D,$ where  $g$ is analytic on $D$ and $g(z_0)\ne 0.$  And for $z\in D$ we have $g(z)=g(z_0)(1+h(z))$ where $\lim_{z\to z_0; z\in D}|h(z)|=0.$

(2).Since $n\geq 2$ and $g(z_0)\ne 0,$ if $U$ is any open subset of  $\mathbb C$ with  $z_0\in U,$ there exists $z_U\in (U\cap D)$ \ $\{z_0\}$ such that $(z_U-z_0)^ng(z_0)\in \mathbb R^+.$

(3).Now let  $U$ be an open disc centered at $z_0$, with small enough radius  that $z\in U\cap D\implies |h(z)|<1/2.$ So $|h(z_U|<1/2.$ We have   $$f(z_U)=f(z_0)+d+h(z_U)d$$ where $d=(z_U-z_0)^n(z_U-z_0)^n>0.$ Recalling that $f(z_0)>0$ we have $$|f(z_U)|\geq |f(z_0)+d|-|h(z_U)d|=f(z_0)+d-|h(z_U)d|> f(z_0) +d/2>f(z_0)=|f(z_0)|,$$ contrary to $|f(z_0|=\max \{|f(z)|:z\in D\}.$

Remark: Step (2) is valid because $n\geq 2.$ It would not be valid for $n=1.$

Comment: in short words : $f(z_0+z) \approx f(z_0) + C z^n$. drawing the set of points $|z| < \epsilon$ such that $|f(z_0) + C z^n| > |f(z_0)|$, and we get that its intersection with the disk $|z+z_0| < r$ is empty implies that $n = 1$.